# Styling widgetized wordpress menus

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm really trying to get my head around how these menus work. I haven't got a clue how to style them properly. I've heard they provide default code every time you register a menu, how can I style this one properly? Basically I'm trying to widgetize this HTML menu, but it's not happening.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 column">
    <ul class="button-group radius even-5">
    <li><a href="#" class="large button what">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="large button what">Marketplace</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="large button what">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="large button what">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="large button what">Reviews</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I have this in the functions bit:

```
<?php

function register_my_menu() {
register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

?>
```

I'm trying to use this Wordpress code to display the menu where I want it, but I haven't got a clue what I need to change in order for it to use the HTML code I want it to, can someone please help?

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu' => 'Categories', 'container_class' => 'main-menu', 'container_id' => 'header', 'theme_location'  => 'header') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a [walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker):

so in your case:

**add this to your functions.php**

```
// ******************* Custom Walker Menus ****************** //
class Class_Name_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
    {
        /**
         * Start the element output.
         *
         * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
         * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
         * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
         * @return void
         */
         function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="'.str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', 'menu-'.strtolower($item->title))).' ' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="large button what">';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
     */
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
    }
```

**and add this to your theme where you want the menu to display:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu' => 'Categories', 'container' => false', 'theme_location'  => 'header-menu', 'items_wrap' => '<div class="row"><div class="large-12 column"><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s button-group radius even-5">%3$s</ul></div></div>', 'walker' => new Class_Name_Walker) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, do i add the code to the functions with what I already have? If so it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @jamhunn89 yes. Leave your code as it was...I realized the theme_location in the callback was wrong..I updated my answer

Comment: Seems to have worked a treat thanks very much! If I wanted to add another navigation just below it would I create another walker? Thanks.

Comment: @jamhunn89 - if you want the same output, No. just call it again with the custom walker. `'walker' => new Class_Name_Walker`

Comment: I thought I did! It's slightly different actually, and in actual fact it shares the same <divs> as the above one. It just has a differrent ul class and different li class and begins right after </ul>, can't put the code here unfortunately. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah I see, I figured it out, I just created the same walker and changed the list code at the bottom and changed the code slightly on the original menu! Thanks again for your help appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress' wp_nav_menu has it's own format for the HTML it creates. The default format looks nothing like yours.

Your options are:

1. Let wp_nav_menu create the HTML it wants and then style that HTML however you need it.
2. Write a custom Walker (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) and tell wp_nav_menu to use that instead of the default. You can then create HTML that looks like whatever you want.

Unless you have requirements that cannot be satisfied by the standard HTML, I'd recommend #1.

Also, look carefully at the reference for wp_nav_menu. It has lots of parameters, including some that let you change the HTML it spits out.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll give this a shot thanks to yours and Marks help!